# Make a gameobject follow one of its components?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a controllable ball that uses the physics engine. It looks like this in the hierarchy..

```
gameobject
     Camera
     Sphere
```

You apply physics forces to the sphere with the input. I'd like my camera to follow the ball and also have the whole thing under one parent as it is now, but as you can likely tell if I make the gameobject move to the Sphere then this will, in turn, move the sphere and I will get exponential movement.
I'm sure there is an easy solution to this, I have just had too many mince pies and Irish mist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just used a blank gameobject, so it looks like this now..

```
Blank gameobject
      controller gameobject
          camera
      Sphere
```